# Regex to match a exactly a word but accept a one-letter error

Tags: javascript, regex

I'd like to know if there was a way to match words with regex in javascript, but that can accept one spelling error (one letter change, a missing letter, or one more letter).

Examples. Here I have an exact matching :

```
function isWordInSentence(s, w) {
    s = s.toLowerCase();
    w = w.toLowerCase();
    return new RegExp('\\b'+w+'\\b').test(s);
}

var word = 'bird';

console.log(isWordInSentence('I like my bird', word)); //True
console.log(isWordInSentence('I use thunderbird', word)); //False
```

Already, the case is out of the question, but I would like something that could accept these kind of things :

```
console.log(isWordInSentence('I like my birds', word)); //True
console.log(isWordInSentence('I like my birdd', word)); //True
console.log(isWordInSentence('I like my beard', word)); //False
console.log(isWordInSentence('I use thunderbird', word)); //False
```

I know for basic language it could bring a lot of false positives like this one :

```
console.log(isWordInSentence('Do you bid?', word)); //True
```

But I'm wishing to use this system on names, as they are easy to spell wrong.

Comment: No, just a regex won't be enough to check there's only a letter of difference. There are many libraries for looking for near words and there are standard distances on words (look for Levenshtein for example), but nothing so easy to use.

Comment: Regex isn't really suitable for this.  You are looking for something like SOUNDEX.  I don't think it exists in native JavaScript, but there might be some libraries which support it.

Comment: Thanks for the advices, I'll go see everything, I remember now Levenshtein but couldn't quite remember how it was called before to search for it

Answer (score 0):

What you actually want is a fuzzy string search/match.

There is a own branch of computer science that deals with this [problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximate_string_matching) and there are many algorithms out. I would suggest to use one of the established JavaScript fuzzy search libraries, like [Fuse.js](https://github.com/krisk/fuse), [fuzzysearch](https://github.com/bevacqua/fuzzysearch), or maybe [fuzzyset.js](https://github.com/Glench/fuzzyset.js).

Here is a [Fuse.js example](http://fusejs.io/):

```js
var books = [{
  'ISBN': 'A',
  'title': "Old Man's War",
  'author': 'John Scalzi'
}, {
  'ISBN': 'B',
  'title': 'The Lock Artist',
  'author': 'Steve Hamilton'
}]

var options = {
  keys: ['title', 'author'],
  id: 'title'
}
var fuse = new Fuse(books, options)

console.log(fuse.search('ol\' man'));
console.log(fuse.search('Locke'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fuse.js/3.2.1/fuse.min.js"></script>
```